# C# Speed Up Writing from Response Stream to ViewStream

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking, async-await, io

I have this code that is asynchronously splitting a file into parts, and downloading them using HTTP content range. It then writes the downloaded data to a ViewStream on a Memory Mapped file. I am currently reading from the response stream into a buffer, then writing all the data from the buffer into the ViewStream. Is there a more efficient/faster way to do this? I am not really concerned about memory use, but I am trying to maximize speed. Pieces is a list that contains value tuples indicating the (Start, End) for the piece of the file, and httpPool is a object pool with a bunch of preconfigured HTTP Clients. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```cs
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(pieces,
                        new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
                        async (piece, cancellationToken) =>
                        {
                            //Get a http client from the pool and request for the content range
                            var client = httpPool.Get();
                            var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri(url) };
                            request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(piece.Item1, piece.Item2);
                            
                            //Request headers so we dont cache the file into memory
                            if (client != null)
                            {
                                var message = await client.SendAsync(request,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                                if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                    //Get the content stream from the message request
                                    using (var streamToRead = await message.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
                                    {
                                        //Create a memory mapped stream to the mmf with the piece offset and size equal to the response size
                                        using (var streams = mmf.CreateViewStream(piece.Item1,message.Content.Headers.ContentLength!.Value,MemoryMappedFileAccess.Write))
                                        {
                                            //Copy from the content stream to the mmf stream
                                            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                                            int offset, bytesRead;
                                            // Until we've read everything
                                            do
                                            {
                                                offset = 0;
                                                // Until the buffer is very nearly full or there's nothing left to read
                                                do
                                                {
                                                    bytesRead = await streamToRead.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(offset, bufferSize - offset),cancellationToken);
                                                    offset += bytesRead;
                                                } while (bytesRead != 0 && offset < bufferSize);

                                                // Empty the buffer
                                                if (offset != 0)
                                                {
                                                    await streams.WriteAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, offset),cancellationToken);
                                                }
                                            } while (bytesRead != 0);

                                            streams.Flush();
                                            streams.Close();
                                        }

                                        streamToRead.Close();
                                    }
                                }

                                message.Content.Dispose();
                                message.Dispose();
                            }

                            request.Dispose();
                            httpPool.Return(client);
                        });
```

Comment: you could try to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorypool-1?view=net-6.0 instead of creating new buffers

Comment: @musium Thanks! Didn’t  think of this. I was trying to figure out how to use StackAlloc inside the annon function haha

Comment: @gregyjames allocating the buffer once is not going to have an impact on the method's performance. I am sure this is not the bottleneck. Using a pooled buffer is nice I suppose, but it is not going to do almost anything in this case. Also, using stack memory, which doesn't even make any sense as the method may easily be handled by a different thread after each await, is not going to help you. Stack memory isn't magically faster than heap memory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much it is going to help, but I tried to do something. How well does it work?

I also did some refactoring, so here are some notes:

- Do not call `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` manually if you already have a `using` block or a `using` statement. All it does is add noise to your code and confuse anyone reading it. In fact, almost never call `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` manually at all.
- Do you realize `client` would never be returned to the pool if any exception occurred in the method? You need to do these things in a `finally` block or by using an `IDisposable` struct which returns `client` to the pool in it's `Dispose()` implementation. (also, `request` would not be disposed in the method if any exception occurred, add `using`)
- Whenever you can, prefer if statements that return early rather than ones that wrap the entire rest of the method. The latter is hard to read and maintain.
- You are not really benefiting from Parallel as 99% of the method is asynchronously waiting for IO. Just use `Task.WhenAll()` instead.
- I got rid of the custom buffering/copying and just called the `CopyToAsync()` method on `message.Content` which accepts a `Stream`. It should help the performance, probably. I reckon it has to be better optimized than the simplest possible buffer thingee.

Code:

```
await Task.WhenAll(pieces.Select(p => DownloadToMemoryMappedFile(p)));

// change the piece type from dynamic to what you need
async Task DownloadToMemoryMappedFile(dynamic piece, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    //Get a http client from the pool and request for the content range
    var client = httpPool.Get();

    try
    {
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri(url) };

        //Request headers so we dont cache the file into memory
        request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(piece.Item1, piece.Item2);

        if (client is null)
        return;

        using var message = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (!message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return;

        //Create a memory mapped stream to the mmf with the piece offset and size equal to the response size
        using var streams = mmf.CreateViewStream(piece.Item1, message.Content.Headers.ContentLength!.Value, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Write);

        await message.Content.CopyToAsync(streams).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        httpPool.Return(client);
    }
}
```